# Excel Data entry forms in VBA

Tags: forms, vba, excel, excel-2010

I am very new to VBA and have been searching to try to figure this out but with no luck.

I am trying to make a form that pops up and has a bunch of different fields to enter and then when the form is submitted, the information is input into separate, specific cells. Also, once the information is input into the cells, it needs to be printed for our records. One last thing to add is that I need some of the fields to disappear if they are empty on the form so that they do not print.

I have a lot of fields for this and all that I have found is how to insert into a new row. If this can be done it would help me out a LOT. If anyone can point me in the right direction then I may be able to figure some out on my own I am fairly literate in HTML so I am able to do some coding.

The fields I have to enter:

```
Deposited By:
Number of Deposits:
Total Checks:
Electronic Deposit Number:
Electronic Deposit Number:
Manual Deposit Number:
Deposit Amount:
Deposit Amount:
Deposit Amount:
Houston Depos:
Dallas Depos:
Austin Depos:
Houston Video:
Dallas Video:
Austin Video:
Houston Records:
```

I will also need to add a button or make the form popup whenever the spreadsheet is opened so that the information can be entered but I believe that may be a little easier to figure out. Along with pre-filling the form with the information already on the page so that it can be edited.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more details you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to answer a few of your questions that you had so hopefully you can write some of your own code:

Form popup whenever the spreadsheet is opened (Placed in the ThisWorkbook code):

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

You can also add a button in the Worksheet and assign it a macro which uses UserForm1.Show.

For the pre-filling the form with information from the sheet use commands like this (Placed in your UserForm code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    txtDepositedBy.Text = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")
End Sub
```

To print your sheets use the Sheets.PrintOut Method:

```
ActiveSheet.PrintOut
'or
Sheets("Sheet3").PrintOut
```

It has these inputs:

```
.PrintOut(From, To, Copies, Preview, ActivePrinter, PrintToFile, Collate, PrToFileName, IgnorePrintAreas)
```

To take your inputs from text boxes and other elements, you can use commands like these:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = TextBox1.Text
'or
Sheets("Sheet3").Range("B2").Value = ComboBox1.Text
```

This should cover a lot of your questions. If you have anymore just let me know and I'll add to the post.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply! I will work on this and let you know how it comes out but this will definitely point me in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you very much! this has definitely helped me in making my form and data entry much much easier!
I had a little bit of a hard time at first but I finally figured everything out and now it is complete and does everything that I want it to do I even set a macro to open it when ctrl+f is pressed. You are a genius and a TREMENDOUS help! 

Thanks very much

-Dominic

Comment: @user3230051 Glad I could help! Let me know if you need anymore help.